# ReSharper NuGet autoresolver

Tags: nuget, resharper, resharper-9.0, resharper-9.1

Is there any chance to setup ReSharper 9.1 to auto resolve NuGet packages? I mean when I type and I do not have reference to xUnit.net and press Alt+Enter ReSharper installs xUnit.net via NuGet.

```
[Fact]
void TestMethod()
{
    Location loc;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's available in ReSharper 9.1 (free update).
See [Find types on NuGet](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2015/04/08/meet-resharper-9-1-resharper-c-1-0-dottrace-6-1-and-more-resharper-ultimate-product-updates/) at our blog post.

Comment: How can I enable it? I looked for it in settings, but unsuccessfully. http://i.imgur.com/c7VcEH8.png

Comment: You don't have to enable it manually, it's enabled by default in ReSharper 9.1 and available over unresolved type references (red code): http://i.imgur.com/ofRhKEU.png